# How to define mappings with OneToMany relation | VichUploaderBundle

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

Is it possible to define mapping on OneToMany Or OneToOne relation within parent Entity ? I don't find any documentation for the moment about that.

Actually done:

Entity;

```php
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Asset", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
private $image;
```

Asset:

```php
class Asset
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $imageName;
```

EntityType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('aaset', AssetType::class, [
                'label' => 'label'
            ])
```

Asset Type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
$builder
            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, [
                'label'        => 'Image',
                'required'     => false,
                'allow_delete' => false,
                'download_uri' => false,
                'image_uri'    => true
            ])
```

VichUploader Definition for Asset:

```
App\Entity\Asset:
  imageFile:
    mapping: images
    filename_property: imageName
```

VichUploader Definition for Entity:

```
App\Entity\Entity:
  oneToOne:
    image:
      mapping: other_mapping
      filename_property: imageName
```

Someone already solve this problem ? 
Thanks for your help.

Tony

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? It's not clearly described. So `Entity` is i.e. a `User` and `Asset` would be i.e. a `ProfilePicture`? And you want to store `User` and `ProfilePicture` entities in separate database tables with a join-column like `user_id` in the `profile_pictures` table? Then you want to have a single form where you can change the `ProfilePicture` of a `User`? I guess you're already using a form to enter the data. Add that form to the question please!

Comment: Hello, 
The goal is to define VichUploader mapping according to Entity Class.
I need different file folder according to parent class. 

I just add form type to the question. 
Thanks for helping

Comment: So according to my example if `ProfilePicture` was used within `User` the uploaded files should be stored in i.e. `uploads/user/profile_pictures` and if `ProfilePicture` was used in say an `Admin` class the pictures should go to `uploads/admin/profile_pictures` but you want to re-use the `ProfilePictureType` form and the `ProfilePicture` class for both?

Comment: Did you just "invent" that mapping for `Entity` in the question yourself to serve as an example what you'd like to achieve? There is no `oneToOne` configuration key in the "[Configuration Reference](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration_reference.md)" for the bundle. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I just want tu reuse Asset class but with different VichUploader mapping.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use an abstract base-class, extend it twice like `UserProfilePicture` and `AdminProfilePicture` in my example and then create two different mappings? Or would that be the solution?

Comment: _Did you just "invent" that mapping for Entity_  
Yes, i got inspired by doctrine entity class definition in yaml. 
[Configuration Reference for Mapping](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/mapping/yaml.md)

Comment: Well this assumes a bi-directional relation between `Asset` and `Entity` because in terms of OOP the `Asset` needs to know which exact `Entity` object it is added/attached to. Asking for further clarification ... What exactly in the mapping would you like to change? If it's just the directory where the images are stored this could be solved with a custom directory-namer.

Comment: Thanks @NicolaiFröhlich, the directory namer do the trick !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @NicolaiFröhlich answer is correct, I need to use directory namer.